# How to get ValueMember value from ComboBox C#?

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

I'm having some trouble trying to get the ValueMember value I've set. I'm trying to use a combobox to read XML data to textbox. Here's my code:

```
    private void zamowienie_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        DataSet dsSet = new DataSet();
        dsSet.ReadXml("E:\\baza\\spis_klientow.xml");
        comboBox2.DataSource = dsSet.Tables["spis_klientow"];
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ID";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "Name";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "Phone";

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("E:\\baza\\spis_klientow.xml");

        foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["spis_klientow"].Rows)
        {
            label10.Text = item[1].ToString();
            label11.Text = item[2].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you rephrase what actually are you trying to achieve

Comment: Read selected combobox  item from xml file to textboxes

Comment: Then use the combobox not the dataset

Comment: Check the instructions on combobox properties SelectedItem and SelectedValue

Comment: I don-t know how to do it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: somebody will write correct code for me?

Comment: Don't reload that xml file in the SelectedIndexChanged event.  You need to move your ds DataSet declaration into your form's scope (out of the load event) so that you can access it from your SelectedIndexChanged event.  It's not clear why you set the ValueMember twice, nor why ID is the DisplayMember (it sounds backwards).  Iterating over the rows collection makes no sense to populate those labels: just use the SelectedIndex on the Rows collection, since that's probably the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a `DataTable` as `ComboBox` data source, the `ComboBox.Items` collection is populated with `DataRowView` objects. Then you can use [ComboBox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var source = (DataRowView)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
    label10.Text = source["Name"].ToString();
    label11.Text = source["Phone"].ToString();
    // ...
}
```

However, there is a better way. WinForms data binding infrastructure supports such scenario without a need to hook into a concrete control events. All you need is to bind combo box and text boxes to one and the same data source (`DataTable` in your case).

Here is a full working example of the data binding "magic" in action:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var form = new Form();
            var comboBox = new ComboBox { Left = 16, Top = 16, DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList };
            var textBoxID = new TextBox { Left = 16, Top = comboBox.Bottom + 8 };
            var textBoxName = new TextBox { Left = 16, Top = textBoxID.Bottom + 8 };
            var textBoxPhone = new TextBox { Left = 16, Top = textBoxName.Bottom + 8 };
            form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { comboBox, textBoxID, textBoxName, textBoxPhone });

            // Begin essential part
            var dataSource = GetData();

            textBoxID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSource, "ID");
            textBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSource, "Name");
            textBoxPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSource, "Phone");

            comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
            comboBox.DataSource = dataSource;

            // End essential part
            Application.Run(form);
        }

        static DataTable GetData()
        {
            //DataSet dsSet = new DataSet();
            //dsSet.ReadXml("E:\\baza\\spis_klientow.xml");
            //return dsSet.Tables["spis_klientow"];

            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Phone");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                table.Rows.Add(i, "Name" + i, "Phone" + i);
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```